# WebOS : how to test if a file exists?

Tags: webos

Is it possible to test if a file exists in WebOS before proceeding with a download using the download manager service?

By default the method "download" will add an underscore + number to avoid overwriting, but what i'm trying to do is to avoid downloading a file if it already exists on the local /media/internal/files folder...

I looked all over the web but to no avail...
Any clue?
Thanks!

Comment: I guess you ask because you don't get the performance you want. But the OS really should handle giving you the local file upon access of the same URL, regardless of local renaming. Just wanted to say that in my experience it's best to not do caching or similar things yourself but see if there's some other reason for bad performance. If the URL isn't the same, then it's another matter, of course.

Comment: i'm not sure i understand your answer. let me try to explain better what i'm trying to do: the user can listen to a streaming mp3 file, if he likes it he can then click a "download" button. The thing is, i want to make sure that if a file with the same filename exists already in the target dir, the download won't happen to save bandwidth and prevent the user from downloading a file already downloaded previously...

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most straightforward way is to use an Ajax request to try to read the file.
http://forums.precentral.net/web-os-development/196320-how-parse-text-file-pres-file-system-into-app.html

If you can't read the file, it obviously hasn't been downloaded yet.

---

Edited to add the following from the webOS 1.4 release notes:

For Ajax.Request, **if the file being requested does not exist, the request no longer gets a "404", which is considered a failure, but a "0", which is considered a success.** You will need to modify your code to look for a transport.status of 0 for a file that does not exist, or 200 for a file that does. See [the Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest#section_3) for more information. Example:

```
new Ajax.Request('/media/internal/my.file', {
    method: 'get',
    onSuccess: function(transport) {
        //This is new for 1.4, we have to check the status of 
        //the transport object to see if the file exists or not.
        if (transport.status == 200)
            Mojo.Log.info('200 = http ok, file exists')
        else if (transport.status == 0)
            Mojo.Log.info('0 = response was empty, file does not exist')
    },
    onFailure: function(transport) {
        Mojo.Log.info('In 1.3.5 if the file didn’t exist the request would return here')
    }
});
```

Comment: i tried that but it always returns true for some reason... ?!

Comment: (and the undocumented "palmGetResource" call is only for text files)

Comment: Weird. I would have expected that Ajax.request would work. I'm about 80% sure I'm seen that done before. Will check it as soon as my phone finishes a software update...

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a private service that leverages NodeJS.

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/fs.html#fs.statSync